# Python's `self` argument for class defined wrapped func

Tags: python, python-3.6

There is a simplified code I have:

```py
class A:
    def foo(*args, **kwargs):
        def foo_sub(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"foo args: {args}")
        return foo_sub

    def bar(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"bar args: {args}")


a = A()


class B:
    foo = a.foo(1)
    bar = a.bar


a.foo(2)()
a.bar()

B.foo()
B.bar()

B().foo()
B().bar()
```

And there is output:

```
foo args: ()
bar args: (<__main__.A object at 0x7f9763e38080>,)
foo args: ()
bar args: (<__main__.A object at 0x7f9763e38080>,)
foo args: (<__main__.B object at 0x7f9763e38828>,)
bar args: (<__main__.A object at 0x7f9763e38080>,)
```

I need to wrap `foo` func in `A` class and I really don't understand why does `B().foo()` passes `self` as argument? How can I prevent it?

More complicated code example: https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/python-3-2uVmcT

Comment: Because you basically define `def foo(*args, **kwargs): ...` as normal method of `B`, and it gets passed `self` the same way as any other method.

Comment: Use a ``staticmethod`` if you don't want functions in the class namespace to receive ``self``/``cls``. It doesn't matter where the function was defined, as long as it ends up in the class namespace it defaults to being used as a method.

Comment: @deceze, thank you for your reply. Is there any way to mark that `foo` is not normal method of `B`, why for `bar` it is working as expected?

Comment: You have updated the question. In your code before, the `bar` doesn't show the argument for `self` because `bar` catches it on its own variable different from the `args` and `kwargs` which is the one you are printing `def bar(self, *args, **kwargs)`. While foo actually returns foo_sub which doesn't accept self thus it goes to *args which is then displayed by your code `def foo_sub(*args, **kwargs):`. So it's not actually that "bar is working as expected", it's just that you defined the function to catch it in its own `self` variable (unlike foo_sub) and then print the rest of *args **kwargs.

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano yea, I messed it, and that's why I updated the question.
But in current code I also get unexpected `<__main__.B object at 0x7f9763e38828>` when I call `B().foo()`

Comment: It's not unexpected. `B.foo` is basically `foo_sub`. It gets passed a `self` when called as an instance method. `foo_sub` doesn't explicitly accept `self`, but accepts it as part of `*args`.

Comment: Try this: `foo = staticmethod(a.foo(1))`

Comment: @kaya3 thank you. It work's great! But maybe is there any other solution, because I trying to implement some base class for datetime rages, where we pass range as class variable `DATETIME_RANGE = datetime_range.yesterday` or `DATETIME_RANGE = datetime_range.n_days(7)` and it's not good to wrap with `staticmethod` here. Some related code example https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/python-3-2uVmcT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @kaya3 for giving a good idea with `staticmethod` and also everyone who replied!

I found a solution with metaclass

```
class BMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        if isinstance(dct.get("foo"), FunctionType):
            dct["foo"] = staticmethod(dct["foo"])
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)


class B(metaclass=BMeta):
    foo = a.foo(1)
    bar = a.bar
```

https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/python-3-BaZXiA

Comment: Is there any reason why you go to the length of using a purpose-built metaclass instead of just defining the single thing you want to be a ``staticmethod`` as a ``staticmethod `` – i.e. ``foo = staticmethod(a.foo(1))``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Look at the code in the sandbox. In the final solution I trying to implement base DatetimeRangeMixin, which can be used by other developers for different etl jobs. We just need to inherits from mixin and redefine `DATETIME_RANGE` variable as `datetime_range.yesterday` or `datetime_range.n_days(7)` etc.

Comment: For example:
`DATETIME_RANGE = datetime_range.yesterday`
`DATETIME_RANGE = datetime_range.n_days(7)`

And we donэt want to think wrap `datetime_range.yesterday` or `datetime_range.n_days(7)` with staticmethod or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do here with all this wrappers and stuff. You might want to look at decorators or context managers to cleanly do this.

- https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-decorator
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types

Answering your question, one way of doing this is by defining static methods as also already pointed out by @MisterMiyagi. Generally in programming, static methods are methods of a class that you can call without needing a class instance/object. This means that such methods has no reference to a class instance's/object's state (in the form of class attributes/fields). In Python, ordinary class methods has access to the instance/object itself via this automatic `self` argument. If you don't want it, define it as a `@staticmethod` instead.

> A static method does not receive an implicit first argument.

- Which is by practice named `self`.
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod

> If you access a method (a function defined in a class namespace)
> through an instance, you get a special object: a bound method (also
> called instance method) object. When called, it will add the self
> argument to the argument list.

- "Through an instance" as how you did with `B()` to do `B().foo()`.
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#methods

Quick code to solve your case (note that as I pointed out earlier, there are better alternatives to this):

```
class A:
    @staticmethod  # Or use the inline-decorator stlye as @kaya3 mentioned
    def foo(*args, **kwargs):
        def foo_sub(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f"foo args: {args}")
        return foo_sub

    @staticmethod
    def bar(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"bar args: {args}")


a = A()


class B:
    @staticmethod
    def foo(*args, **kwargs):
        return a.foo(1)(*args, **kwargs) 

    @staticmethod
    def bar(*args, **kwargs):
        return a.bar(*args, **kwargs)


a.foo(2)()
a.bar()

B.foo()
B.bar()

B().foo()
B().bar()
```

Output:

```
foo args: ()
bar args: ()
foo args: ()
bar args: ()
foo args: ()
bar args: ()
```

Otherwise if you really badly want to skip the `self` attribute altogether and hack all the way through, you could trigger `obj.method.__func__(*args, **kwargs)` as described in https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#methods

- WARNING: This suggestion is hackish. Proceed with caution :)

Comment: Updated the code. I forgot to pass `*args, **kwargs` in the call to `a.foo(1)()`. Same output as no arguments has been passed yet.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. 
I'm trying to implement some datetime range mixin where we can define date range in python code,  which will be translated into start/end variables, for example: `last.week`, `last.month` or `last.n_days`. And for `week/month/..` all is fine (when we know period), but I faced with some problems when trying to implement `n_days` method. 
[This code example](https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/python-3-2uVmcT) raises `TypeError: n_days() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given` for n_days range.

Comment: I tried your code. The usage of `self.DATETIME_RANGE()` is the exact code that causes you problems. As in this reference https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#methods "If you access a method (a function defined in a class namespace) through an instance, you get a special object: a bound method (also called instance method) object. When called, it will add the self argument to the argument list.". Quick fix to your code is to change the call to `self.DATETIME_RANGE.__func__()` but it seems hackish, not a good suggestion :)

Comment: Or to avoid the self, maybe you would want to encapsulate `DATETIME_RANGE` into an entrypoint method within Foo and Bar which in turn would actually call `datetime_range.n_days(7)(*args, **kwargs)` so that the self argument wouldn't be passed already.